# How to rename excel file when exporting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, export-to-excel

Is there anyway that I can rename exported excel file based on user filtering. Currently the code that i used generate random name.

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
    var url='data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent($('#tableWrap').html()) 
    location.href=url
    return false
    })
})
```

Export button code is really simple.

```
<button>Export</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the name the file has when it is being downloaded, then no. Especially when this is done with no user interaction. However, there is Chrome's download attribute for links.

Links:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp